# The underlying space of an affine open dense subscheme

Tags: gn.general-topology, schemes

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme, $U\subset X$ be an affine open dense subscheme. Is the underlying space of $U$ necessarily homeomorphic to the underlying space of $X$?

Comment: A variant was asked here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331673/the-underlying-space-of-open-dense-subscheme but Francesco's answer applies to both.

Comment: OK I see, I lost the assumption "affine" from the linked question.

Answer (score 6):

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, ad take $X=\mathbb{P}^2_k$, $U=\mathbb{A}^2_k$.

Then $X$ and $U$ are not homeomorphic, since $U$ contains two disjoint, Zariski-closed, irreducible subsets made of more than one point (think of two parallel lines), but this is not possible in $X$ because of Bézout theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Let $X=\operatorname{Spec}R$, where $R$ is a discrete valuation ring. It consists if two points $x,y$ where $x$ is the generic point and $y$ is a closed point. Then $\{x\}$ is an open, dense, affine subset which is not homeomorphic to $X$, since it has fewer points.